# babashka does not run script - new to babashka

Tags: cygwin, babashka

I am new to babashka. When I run a script it appears to do nothing. On cygwin:

```
$ bb --version
babashka v1.1.172

$ bb '(+ 1 2 3)'
6

$ echo '(+ 1 2 3)' > t.clj

$ cat t.clj
(+ 1 2 3)

$ bb t.clj
        <== nothing here!
```

The same thing is happening on the Windows command prompt.

Answer (score 1):

never mind - the `--prn` option worked:

```
$ bb --prn t.clj
6
```

However, the [related section](https://book.babashka.org/#_running_babashka) on the babashka book has the script just like I have it on my question and does not mention the need to use the `--prn` option

Comment: I'll update it. Next time, feel free to post an issue.