# couldn't find the babashka script output

Tags: clojure, babashka

I'm learning babashka using the free ebook [bobooka.pdf](https://github.com/braveclojure/babooka/blob/main/babooka.pdf).

The first exercise in this book is running hello.clj.

[image: babooka hello.clj error]

When I run the first example in the cli with command `bb hello.clj` I don't see any output.

However if I run the expression in bb repl I see it print the result to the console.

[image]

The babashka version that I'm using is `v1.3.176`.

[image]

Any Idea why it is not printing the result to console in first case?

Comment: Try using `println` just to see if you get any output

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking
a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [babashka does not run script - new to babashka](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75296536/babashka-does-not-run-script-new-to-babashka)

Comment: This also got already fixed in the book: https://github.com/braveclojure/babooka/commit/5060609dd5cc45afbb40cb436d9d974901817f9c